# How to show things different based on theme?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-darkmode

I made some spinners in my activity and made drawable resources for them, but when I turn off dark mode on my phone it looks weird. how can I define things to change when I am not in dark mode.
For example, I made borders of spinners in white color but it is not visible when I turn off my dark mode. I want it to turn black when I turn the dark mode off. Can anyone tell me how can I do this?